# How to include all Cpp libraries for CLION

Tags: c++, cmake, ide, clion

I am using CLION IDE for C++ coding. The IDE is pretty good but I dont get the autocompletion for the included libraries.

For example :-

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
vector<int> A;
A.
}
```

this line gives no suggestion and i learn that it can be done using editing CMAKE file! Can anyone guide me further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clion parses the CMakeLists.txt file in order to build it's index. I recommend you read CMake documentation (or Clion documentation, for that matter).

For example, this is the default CMakeLists.txt I use:

```sh
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(my_proj)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${my_flags}"

file(GLOB src_files src/*.cpp include/*.hpp)

add_executable(my_proj ${src_files})
```